# cms for picture management website?

Tags: web, content-management-system, image

my friend wants to set up a website. He is photographer,
and he'd like to document beautiful natural sites of Brazil.

So he'd like a webpage where, everytime he's been on a trip,
he'd upload his pics. He envisions a list of clickable expeditions;
on each of the expeditions you could have pics, a map, and
some description. His was inspired by:
[Gaia Expediçoes](http://www.gaiaexpedicoes.com/index1.html)

Preferrably, he would have nothing to do with programming, HTML, etc.

I thought of a CMS. Can someone recommend an appropriate CMS 
(possibly open source, ideally free)? Or any other suggestions?

Thanks
fabio

Comment: ASP, PHP, Python? What language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several. The first that I think of is [drupal](http://www.drupal.org) which is a fully functioning cms with many add on modules and themes. You can create an entire website without doing any coding and many web host has it installed.

I know that [godaddy.com](http://www.godaddy.com) has drupal and others installed in their hosting packages. You can customize and select a theme and choose the image management modules etc.

One option to look for is the [gallery assist module](http://drupal.org/project/modules?text=image%20gallery).

Comment: UGH -- Drupal requires tinkering, whether you're doing coding or not. It's not aimed at plug-and-play users, I don't know of any CMS that is.

Comment: @Jason S That is true...It would be hard to find a cms that does not require some configuration. The best we can hope for is that the configs would be easy enough for a novice. I sometimes have difficulty understanding the configs for drupal and other cms myself so I'm not sure how easy thay are for the novice. I think, if you use it as is with absolutely no changes it would be easy. But If you want to change layout and style and themes etc then you pay the price,

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Joomla is a good candidate. Although Drupal is as earlier said very powerful but a bit hard to master in the beginning.

Joomla has extensions that allows you to make many [things with images](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images). It's open source and free.

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy is one, if not the most, poor, chunky and unstable webhosting.

There are plenty of webhosting that bring FANTASTICO / Install Central.  Fantastico and Install Central is a "one-click" cms install.

My hosting is powweb (slow as hell) have Install central, this allow the installation of (gallery style)

Gallery2 : http://gallery.menalto.com/features
Coppernite : http://coppermine-gallery.net/
Zen Photo : http://zenphoto.org/

Comment: @magallanes Thanks for the feedback on godaddy. I was considering them but I think I will look further before I make a decision. Hmm...I wonder if the question of drupal hosting was ever asked on SO?